# Upload file to Sharepoint folder

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint

I've been able to upload a file to Documents, however I can't figure out how I can upload a file to one of the folders in 'Documents. I've checked out a bunch of resources online and I can't seem to piece it together. I'm trying to make this work within a C# WPF desktop application using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.

Current working code for loading file to Documents

```
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"sharepointURL"))
        {
            // Credentials

            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
            context.Credentials = new 
            SharePointOnlineCredentials("myusername", password);

            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            context.Load(list.RootFolder);
            var lib = list.RootFolder.Folders;
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            // Upload/replace file

            string fileName = @"myfilepath.docx";
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                string fileUrl = $@"{list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl}/test.docx";
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, stream, true);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is super simple. I just include the folder name within fileUrl like so:

string fileUrl = $@"{list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl}/subfolder/test.docx";